# How to enter multiple lines in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How does one enter multiple lines of code into the rails console?

--edit with problem trying to solve--

I am trying to get a handle on using the collect method and want to try out the following code in the rails console:

```
first_activities_collection = users.collect |user|
  activities = user.activities
  first = activities.first
```

And having difficulty getting it to execute.

I have tried:

```
first_activities_collection = users.collect |user|
  activities = user.activities;
  first = activities.first;
  end
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong with .collect?

Comment: What exactly do you want to enter? If you start something like a loop the console will detect this and wait with execution until you close the loop. You could use 'rails runner my.rb' if you want to execute code in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `do` keyword in your loop.

Answer (score 5):

Separate them with semicolons. If you are typing at a remote console which responds slowly, this often saves time.

Sometimes when using a remote console, I edit the code which I want to run in a text editor, and then cut-and-paste it all into the console at one go. That way if I need to change something or fix a bug, I don't have to type it all in again.